# Pandas pivot ussing column as suffix

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe like the following example:

| Id | Type | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 1234 | B | 1 | 2 |
| 789 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 789 | B | 1 | 2 |
| 567 | A | 1 | 2 |

And I want to transform to get the following:

| Id | Value_1_A | Value_1_B | Value_2_A | Value_2_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 789 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 567 | 1 |  | 1 |  |

In summary: replicating the value columns using the 'Type' column as a suffix and convert the dataframe to a wide format.

Is there any clean and easy way to do it on pyspark dataframes or pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `pandas` we would [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) then collapse the Multi-Index with [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
new_df = df.pivot(index='Id', columns='Type')
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map('_'.join)
# Or with an explicit format string like:
# new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

`new_df`:

```
     Id  Value_1_A  Value_1_B  Value_2_A  Value_2_B
0   567        1.0        NaN        2.0        NaN
1   789        1.0        1.0        2.0        2.0
2  1234        1.0        1.0        2.0        2.0
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': {0: 1234, 1: 1234, 2: 789, 3: 789, 4: 567},
                   'Type': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'A'},
                   'Value_1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
                   'Value_2': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2}})
```

Comment: thank you, would this accept multiple columns on the index?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In pivot? like `pivot(index=['col1', 'col2'], ...)`?

Comment: If instead of the column 'Id' there is more than one column to identify each registry

Comment: Yes. Just pass a list to pivot. `pivot(index=['id', 'col2', 'col3'], columns='Type')`

Comment: For some reason if I use df.pivot with more than one column as the index I get a "Length mismatch" error. However if I use pd.pivot_table(df,....) keeping the rest of the code the same it works. Regardless, this is what I needed, so thank you very much.

Comment: Depends on a number of factors, but glad you've got it working :)

Comment: `df.columns.map('_'.join')` works fine; unless I missed sth

Comment: No you're 100% correct @sammywemmy the question was kinda open ended so I was trying build a solution that was as flexible as possible.