# Pivot dataframe in pyspark using column for suffix

Tags: pyspark

This question is similar to one I've asked before ([Pandas pivot ussing column as suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68925853/pandas-pivot-ussing-column-as-suffix)) but this time I need to do it using Pyspark instead of Pandas. The problem is as follows.

I have a dataframe like the following example:

| Id | Type | Value_1 | Value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 1234 | B | 1 | 2 |
| 789 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 789 | B | 1 | 2 |
| 567 | A | 1 | 2 |

And I want to transform to get the following:

| Id | Value_1_A | Value_1_B | Value_2_A | Value_2_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 789 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 567 | 1 |  | 1 |  |

In summary: replicating the value columns using the 'Type' column as a suffix and convert the dataframe to a wide format.

One solution I can think of is creating the columns with the suffix manually and then aggregating.

Other solutions I've tried are using pyspark GroupedData pivot function as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'Id': {0: 1234, 1: 1234, 2: 789, 3: 789, 4: 567},
                   'Type': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'A'},
                   'Value_1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
                   'Value_2': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2}}))    
df.groupBy("Id").pivot("Type").avg().show()
```

The issue of this solution is that the resulting dataframe would include the Id column repeated 3 times, and the inability to name the columns adding Type as the suffix, since they would be named liked this:

```
['Id',
 'A_avg(Id)',
 'A_avg(Value_1)',
 'A_avg(Value_2)',
 'B_avg(Id)',
 'B_avg(Value_1)',
 'B_avg(Value_2)']
```

I also tried specifying the value columns to the pivot functions as follows

```
df.groupBy("Id").pivot("Type", values=["Value_1", "Value_2"]).avg().show()
```

This removes the extra Id columns, but the rest of the columns only have null values.

Is there any elegant way to do the transformation I'm attempting on pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

If you don't mind having your `Type` values as column *prefixes* rather than suffixes, you can use a combination of `agg`, `avg`, and `alias`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_pivot = df \
  .groupBy("Id") \
  .pivot("Type") \
  .agg(F.avg("Value_1").alias("Value_1"), F.avg("Value_2").alias("Value_2"))
```

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|Id  |A_Value_1|A_Value_2|B_Value_1|B_Value_2|
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|789 |1.0      |2.0      |1.0      |2.0      |
|567 |1.0      |2.0      |null     |null     |
|1234|1.0      |2.0      |1.0      |2.0      |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Separately, it's worth noting here that the `values` argument in the `pivot` method is used to limit which values you want to retain from your pivot (i.e., `Type`) column. For example, if you only wanted `A` and not `B` in your output, you would specify `pivot("Type", values=["A"])`.

**Option 2:**

If you do still want them as suffixes, you'll likely have to use some regex and `withColumnRenamed`, which could look something like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import re

df_pivot = df \
  .groupBy("Id") \
  .pivot("Type") \
  .agg(F.avg("Value_1"), F.avg("Value_2"))

for col in df_pivot.columns:
  if "avg(" in col:
    suffix = re.findall("^.*(?=_avg\()|$", col)[0]
    base_name = re.findall("(?<=\().*(?=\)$)|$", col)[0]
    df_pivot = df_pivot.withColumnRenamed(col, "_".join([base_name, suffix]))
```

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|Id  |Value_1_A|Value_2_A|Value_1_B|Value_2_B|
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|789 |1.0      |2.0      |1.0      |2.0      |
|567 |1.0      |2.0      |null     |null     |
|1234|1.0      |2.0      |1.0      |2.0      |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: both answers are great, thank you :)

Comment: In case someone might come looking for the same solution, I want to add that you can construct the agg after pivot dynamically, in case you have many value columns, as follows: `aggs = [F.avg(x).alias(x) for x in df.columns if x not in ["Id", "Type"]]` and then replace `.agg(F.avg("Value_1"), F.avg("Value_2"))` with `.agg(*aggs)`.